# Solving potentially infinite recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I want to solve $T(n) = T(\frac{1}{8n}) + 8$, it seems to me that the answer must be infinite since

\begin{align*}
T(n) = T(\frac{1}{8n}) + 8 = T(\frac{1}{8(1/8n)}) + 2 \times 8 = T(n) + 16
\end{align*}
and so $T(n) = \infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: So it is not $\frac{n}{8}$? may be then $T(x) = \text{something}, \forall x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @coffeemath : He's shown $T=T+16$, which isn't a common property of finite things.

Comment: @dEmigOd there was no restriction on $x$, maybe the question is wrong..

Comment: @coffeemath isn't this a valid approach, I was just unrolling the recursion trying to find a pattern

Comment: @coffeemath : You do realize that the function "$16$" is the function that takes its argument, ignores it, and returns $16$, do you not?  So what I have written is exactly equivalent to what you have written without the uninformative "$(n)$"s cluttering the view.

Comment: @EricTowers Point taken. I'll delete some comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct! Here is your method explained slightly clearer:

Let $n=1$. Then, we have $\displaystyle T(1) = T(\frac{1}{8 \cdot 1}) + 8;\ T(1) = T(\frac{1}{8})+8. \quad(\text{equation } 1)$

Now let $n=\frac{1}{8}$. We get $\displaystyle T(\frac{1}{8}) = T(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{8} \cdot 8}) + 8;\ T(\frac{1}{8}) = T(1)+8. \quad(\text{equation } 2)$

Substituting equation $1$ into equation $2$, we have $T(1) = \big(T(1) + 8\big) + 8$. This shows that $0=16$, so the recurrence relation either is infinite, or has no solution.